# Simple exercice with exceptions in java

Tags: programming-languages, java, exception, string

Here's the problem to solve: a method of a class that represents a gas network. This class manages objects of type `Line` that represent each single gas supply line. 
An object of type `Line` is represented by the following members:

- String startCity;
- String endCity;
- int capacityUsed;
- int capacityAvail;
- int maxCapacity;

The method I'm having trouble implementing is:

`boolean carry(String city1, String city2, int capacity)`

Consider all the lines from `city1` to`city2`. For each of these lines
try using `capacity` with the method `use()` (I don't think it's necessary to know how 
`use()` works ). If `use()` throws the exception `CapacitaSuperataException` search
other lines between `city1` and `city2`, if there are no other lines `use()`
must return `False`. If a call to `use()` does not throw `CapacitaSuperataExceptio`n means that the line was assigned the `capacity`, and the method returns `True`.

I tried some solutions but I don't know how to manage exceptions.

Thanks

Comment: Note that if this is an exercise, it's pretty bad in the sense that exceptions are used for non-exceptional circumstances by design. Normally, you should not encounter any exceptions during the runtime of a "good" scenario - and finding no capacity while looking for it would be considered a "good" scenario. (It boggles the mind how many excercises learn you how to do something - correctly - while advocating bad programming practices on other fronts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the try-catch inside a loop covering all suitable lines in your carry-Method:

```
for (Line line : getLines("start", "end"))
{
  try
  {
    line.use(cap);
    System.out.println("Line used, great!");
    return true;
  }
  catch (CapacitaSuperataException e)
  {
    System.out.println("Line full, try next");
  }
}
System.out.println("No line found");
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void use(int desiredCapacity) throws CapacitaSuperataException {
    if(desiredCapacity > maxCapacity) throw CapacitaSuperataException 
    ...
}
public void example() {
    try {
    this.use(999999)
    } catch(CapacitaSuperataException) { /* show error message */ }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i already know how to use exceptions.. the problem is that i have to catch more than one exception  "For each of these lines try the method use()" and when use() throws an CapacitaSuperataException the function must return false only if there are not other items in the list..

Comment: You asked "I tried some solutions but I don't know how to manage exceptions.", well this is how you try/catch exceptions.